# Package fontspec Error: The font "Lato-Lig" cannot be found. \setsansfont

Tags: fonts, packages, fontspec

I get this error `Package fontspec Error: The font "Lato-Lig" cannot be found. \setsansfont` when I run this code:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.25cm, vmargin=0.7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{isodate}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}

\definecolor{date}{HTML}{666666} 
\definecolor{primary}{HTML}{2b2b2b} 
\definecolor{headings}{HTML}{6A6A6A}
\definecolor{subheadings}{HTML}{333333}

% Set main fonts
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Color=primary,Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text, Path = fonts/lato/]{Raleway-ExtraLight}
\newcommand{\custombold}[1]{\color{subheadings}\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Reg}\selectfont #1 \normalfont}
\begin{document}
    
    Hello   
        
        
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, don't keep us in suspense. Does that font exist in `fonts/lato/` (relative to your project)? If so, you might want to add `Extension=.ttf` or `Extension=.otf` to the options, depending on which one it is, or include it in the font name, so it knows to look by filename rather than font family name.